# NFC intent Filter => I/NfcDispatcher(923): Connect to a tech with a different handle

Tags: android, android-intent, nfc

I am working on an NFC application that works perfectly with some VCard tags.

Now, I would like to use some differents tags that the customer sent me.

The Android device (Nexus 4 and Galaxy Nexus) are just making the NFC beep, but no app appears, no intent chooser...

Here is my Manifest entry for the Intent:

```
<activity
    android:name=".ResultActivity"
    android:label="Alcatel Scan"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>

</activity>
```

And here is the associated logcat when I scan the tag:

```
12-28 12:29:35.599: D/ACDB-LOADER(164): ACDB -> send_afe_cal
12-28 12:29:35.609: D/NativeNfcTag(923): Connect to a tech with a different handle
12-28 12:29:35.619: D/alsa_ucm(164): Set mixer controls for HiFi Lowlatency enable 1
12-28 12:29:35.619: D/ALSAModule(164): Device value returned is hw:0,14
12-28 12:29:35.629: D/ALSAModule(164): setHardwareParams: reqBuffSize 1024 channels 2 sampleRate 48000
12-28 12:29:35.629: D/ALSAModule(164): setHardwareParams: buffer_size 2048, period_size 1024, period_cnt 2
12-28 12:29:35.639: D/NativeNfcTag(923): Check NDEF Failed - status = 3
12-28 12:29:35.639: D/NfcDispatcher(923): dispatch tag: TAG: Tech [android.nfc.tech.NfcV, android.nfc.tech.NdefFormatable] message: null
12-28 12:29:35.669: I/NfcDispatcher(923): no match
```

According to this line: "Connect to a tech with a different handle" I really fear that the tag will never be readable by an Android device.. Am I wrong?

Thank a lot for any help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, here is the correct Intent Filter:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"/>
    <meta-data android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
        android:resource="@xml/nfc_tech_filter" />
</intent-filter>

<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: ``<meta-data>`` should be outside of ``<intent-filter>``